# How to give \homepage link another name?

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, cv, url

In OverleafV1 the following code could be used in `moderncv`

```
\homepage{LinkIn.com}{LinkedIn Profile}
```

This would hide the website (`LinkedIn.com`) as a piece of text "LinkedIn Profile".

After the merge ShareLatex/OverleafV2 the double brackets gives an error and only single brackets work.

I have tried to use `\hyperref` and `\url` but the document first begins a few lines under this statement which creates an error.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\homepage{\url{LinkedIn.com}}
\homepage{\hyperref{LinkedIn.com}}
```

Using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/curriculum-vitae/cnzchmjctmwh)

Is there another way around this? thanks

EDIT:

```
\homepage{LinkedIn.com}{LinkedIn Profile} %This code will work in OverleafV1
same code will not work in OverleafV2 or ShareLatex but...

\homepage{LinkedIn.com} %This works in OverleafV2 or ShareLatex but as soon as a second bracket is added it doesn't hide the link in the name.
```

But instead puts the second bracket over the `\firstname{}` text on the pdf.

Maybe this is easier to understand?

EDIT 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 


\usepackage[danish]{babel}%Overskrift på indholdsfortegnelse dansk%
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{X} % Your first name
\familyname{Y} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{A}
\extrainfo{B}
\address{C}{D}
\mobile{E}
\email{F}

\homepage{LinkedIn.com}{LinkedIn Profile}
% The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example



\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{billeder/BxY0owY.png}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2016}{A}{B}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, in newer versions of `moderncv` the command `\homepage` does only use one argument. You want to use two. To get this add the following line to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\homepage}[2]{\def\@homepage{#1}\def\@homepagetitle{#2}}
```

Because `moderncv` adds `\http://` instead today used `\https://` I defined a new command `\httpslink` like

```
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}
```

At last we have to patch in command `\makecvhead` the following line

```
\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}
```

to create the homepage link you want:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{%search
  \makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}{%replace
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@homepagetitle}{}}% \homepagetitle could be empty
    {\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}%
    {\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httpslink[\@homepagetitle]{\@homepage}}}%
  }{%success
  }{%failure
    }
```

Please see that we have to use commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because we have `@` in the code above ...

So with the following compilable MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins

\usepackage[danish]{babel}%Overskrift på indholdsfortegnelse dansk%


\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\newcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\homepage}[2]{\def\@homepage{#1}\def\@homepagetitle{#2}}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{%search
  \makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}{%replace
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@homepagetitle}{}}% \homepagetitle could be empty
    {\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}%
    {\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httpslink[\@homepagetitle]{\@homepage}}}%
  }{%success
  }{%failure
    }
\makeatother % <========================================================

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{X} % Your first name
\familyname{Y} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{A}
\extrainfo{B}
\address{C}{D}
\mobile{E}
\email{F}

\homepage{LinkedIn.com}{LinkedIn Profile}
% The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{example-image}
%\quote{"A witty and playful quotation" - John Smith}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2016}{A}{B}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

you get what you want:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to use this solution, but get the following error: ``Command \httpslink already defined. {\href{https://#2}{#1}}}``. The solution does therefore not work for me. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

`moderncv` has a special command to insert a link to your LinkedIn Profile without showing the complete web address: `\social[linkedin]{LinkedIn Profile}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 


\usepackage[danish]{babel}%Overskrift på indholdsfortegnelse dansk%
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{X} % Your first name
\familyname{Y} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{A}
\extrainfo{B}
\address{C}{D}
\mobile{E}
\email{F}

\social[linkedin]{LinkedIn Profile} 

%\homepage{LinkedIn.com}%{LinkedIn Profile}
% The first argument is the url for the clickable link, the second argument is the url displayed in the template - this allows special characters to be displayed such as the tilde in this example



\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{example-image}



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\cventry{2016}{A}{B}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

[image]